# The calling sequence of pthread_init pthread_lock, pthread_destroy and so on?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

Normally, the correct sequence is something like this:

```
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex,NULL);

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
```

`mutex` should be initialized first, and then `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` can be called in respective thread to protect the critical section, finally `pthread_mutex_destroy` is called to destroy the `mutex` after the completion of all threads.  But if the order is mixed, What would happend?

I disrupt the sequence of the functions  in order to find out the error, but everything seems normal when the sequence is messed in different way. Here is an example.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
static int count = 0;

void* func(void* arg)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    *(int*)arg = *(int*)(arg) + 1;
    printf("thread %d\n", *(int*)arg);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_t tid;
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, (void*)(&count));
        sleep(5);
    }

    printf("the main thread exit normally.\n");
}
```

I want to ask whether the sequence matters to the program. Is there something inside the function to assure the calling sequence, or something else?  If these functions can be used without order, why should `pthread_mutex_init()` and `pthread_mutex_destroy()` be defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is undefined behavior. The implementation may, or may not, print an error, abort the program, or start WW III. Or it may appear to work just fine, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: How do you draw this conclusion, does it depend on the specific implementation on different platform?

Comment: By reading the relevant parts of the POSIX standard. For undefined behavior, an implementation is free to do whatever it wants (e.g. start WW III to punish the user for such an egregious misuse of the provided functionality).